# Minimal typescript definition for existing javascript library

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

I want to use the [neat-csv](https://github.com/sindresorhus/neat-csv) library but it does not provide a typescript definition file. Several blogs mentioned a quick way to create a minimal definition file to get started:

```
declare var neatCsv: any;
```

But I don't know what to do with the definition file. Where should it be located? How do you link the definition file with the actual implementation which is located in `node_modules/neat-csv`. Then how do you import it in an actual typescript file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package used the following module import syntax:

```
const neatCsv = require('neat-csv');
```

This means that the kind of module is that you need don't use exports `{ x }` of default exports `export default x`. What you need is the following:

```
declare module "neat-csv" {
    var neatCsv: (input: any, options?: any) => Promise<any>;
    export = neatCsv;
}
```

You can copy the preceding code in a file named `declarations.d.ts` inside your `src` folder. Then, you will be able to import it and use it as follows:

```
import * as neatCsv from "neat-csv";

let csv = "type,part\nunicorn,horn\nrainbow,pink";
neatCsv(csv, { /* options */ });
```